# Committing units with a warlord

Tags: conquest-lcg

In some situations, you may have units at your HQ with your warlord.
I know when you commit your warlord to a planet,  all the units at HQ come across with the warlord exhausted.

What I want to know is what happens to these units once you win a battle at the planet that is *not* the first planet? Do they go back to HQ with the warlord,  or do they remain committed to that planet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After rereading the '**Learn to Play** rulebook closely, I found the answer on **page 11** (emphasis mine):

> When a player wins a battle at any other planet, his warlord (if it
>   was committed to that planet) returns to his headquarters, maintaining
>   the state (ready or exhausted) it was in at the end of the battle. The
>   planet remains in play, and **other surviving units remain at that
>   planet**, also maintaining their state.

In short, any non warlord units at a planet that is not the first, will remain there after the battle is completed.